# Is there a strictly-libre Cydia repo?

Tags: ios, jailbreak, open-source, license, cydia

The Android equivalent of Cydia is the *F-Droid app*. The associated [F-Droid repo](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/) contains strictly free/libre/open-source software.

Is there an equivalent Cydia repo that only hosts libre software? (A repo where it is trivially easy to filter for libre software is acceptable.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unfortunately, all the repositories host both open and closed source tweaks and there is currently no way to sort a repo by open-source tweaks.